# Error message limit for GHCI?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

When I `:load` a big file with type errors, I get a huge pile of text which becomes hard to navigate.

Is there any way to configure GHCi to display only a few first error messages rather than the whole list?

Comment: If you have a big source file, maybe you could use a smart editor (or IDE) which can show the errors next to the code. Emacs does this (with haskell-mode and FlyMake), for instance.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no option in GHCi to do this at the moment. To workaround the problem, I use `stack build 2>&1 | head -n 30` from the unix shell to view first 30 lines of errors.